# App works fine in android 2.3.7 and not in 4.1.2

Tags: android, jar, android-version

I have an app that works fine in android 2.3.4, 2.3.6 and 2.3.7 but it doesn´t in android 4.1.2 or 4.2.2 (I have no more devices)

The app calls to a jar file that returns a result, when I test the app in 2.3.7 I make the call to the jar and takes the result but when I do it with android 4.1.2 it forces the close. It´s quite weird because the only difference is the OS because the app is the same.

The jar file makes a call to internet, I don´t think this could be the mistake

Thanks again everybody!

Comment: Have you used web services ?

Comment: Please post your Logcat error..

Comment: `The jar file makes a call to internet, I don´t think this could be the mistake` - This could make a huge difference actually.

Comment: Is your jar file externally placed or inside the project itself?

Comment: bet on `NetworkOnMainThreadException`

Comment: where is the jar placed? where do you make the call to the jar? post some code.

Comment: I use HttpClient for the internet. I have no logcat because I have to export the file to be used in the devices. The jar is added in Referenced libraries and Android Dependencies

Comment: this is the manifest <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="13" />

Comment: You are targetting it for API level 13 ? Android 4.1 is API level 16 !! You should be targetting for the latest api level, i.e. 17..

Comment: I did that before and also didn´t work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The jar file makes a call to internet, I don´t think this could be the
>   mistake

=> Sorry dude problem is here, as you said your app is working fine in < 2.3 versions but not in >2.3, reasons behind this failure is **`NetworkOnMainThreadException`**.

**Now, Why this exception is being raised whenever you run app in >2.3 version device?**

=> `NetworkOnMainThreadException` occurs whenever an application attempts to perform a networking operation on its main thread.

### Solutions:

Below are the two solutions to resolve this issue:

1) Standard way is to make webservice call by implementing [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

2) The lazy way of handling this is to turn the check of:

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

Comment: Thanks Paresh, I´m with the standard way as RajaReddy said, thanks for the link

Answer (score 0):

From android Versions 4.0 (ICS) onwards networking operation should be run in AsynTask. 
Run your code in AsyncTask:

```
private class Task extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    private Exception exception;

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... urls) { 
        /// run your network operations here     
        return null;         
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(RSSFeed feed) {

   }     
}

 new Task ().execute();
```

Comment: So RajaReddy what you say is to put the call in the jar in an AsynTask??

Comment: Network related operation should be in asyncTask. i mean calling network jar related functions should be in main thread.

Comment: Thanks RajaReddy I´ll try that and let you know